# How can pass the app instance to route file in ExpressJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I'm using Express framework to develop my backend APIs, but I encounter with one issue today. I have one `server.js` (entry) file from there I want to pass `app` instance to `routes/api.js` file. where I wanted to check if endpoint prefix is `/api/v2` then I want to call the `routes/index.js` file. But I'm unable to achieve this approach. I'm adding my code of `server.js` `routes/api.js` & `routes/index.js` files below.

**Server.js**

```
/** Core Packages */

/** NPM Packages */
const express = require('express');

/** Custom Packages */
const routerApi = require('./routes/api');
const dbConnect = require('./config/database');

const app = express();
dbConnect();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

routerApi(app);

const PORT = 4000;

/** Creating a Server */
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

**routes/api.js**

```
/** Core Packages */

/** NPM Packages */

/** Custom Packages */

const apiRouter = (app) => {
  app.use('/api/v2', require('./index')(app));
};

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
/** Core Packages */

/** NPM Packages */

/** Custom Packages */

const routes = (app) => {
  app.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.path === '/')
      return res.status(200).send({msg: 'Welcome to landing page.'});
  }
}

module.exports = routes;
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (/home/admini/Documents/skreem-api-node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/admini/Documents/skreem-api-node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/home/admini/Documents/skreem-api-node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at apiRouter (/home/admini/Documents/skreem-api-node/routes/api.js:9:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/admini/Documents/skreem-api-node/server.js:52:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this problem? Any kind of help will be appriciated.
Thanks You!

Answer (score 2):

In **server.js** file, add the following at the bottom of your file:

```
module.exports = app;
```

And then require **server.js** in the files where it is needed:

```
const app = require('path to server.js file');
```

Comment: Thanks @stacks I'll follow the way you suggested & get back to you, in case if I would face any issue.